# git +jenkins fetch issue

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

when i checkout code from git repository it gives error like :

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / /Users/shriram/.jenkins/jobs/github1/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@46347456
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision b0a93e1344ac7ce65fbfc34fb2d3b5a8b0a72e05 (origin/master)
Checkout:workspace / /Users/shriram/.jenkins/jobs/github1/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@46347456
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ssh:///shriarm@17.209.10.99 : 22/~/jengittest.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: /opt/local/bin/git fetch -t ssh:///shriram@17.209.10.99 : 22/~/jengittest.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Command "/opt/local/bin/git fetch -t ssh:///shriram@17.209.10.99 : 22/~/jengittest.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message hints at the solution: The host key for `17.209.10.99` is unknown or invalid.

Delete the line with that host from your `.ssh/known_hosts` file. After that, do a manual connect to that host using `ssh shriarm@17.209.10.99` and accept the host key again.